# How to stream webcam to RTMP server using Flash client in browser?

Tags: flash, rtmp

I built quite simple RTMP server with nginx-rtmp-module. It works fine. It also has [example](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/blob/master/test/rtmp-publisher/publisher.html) with Flash Publisher. And it works fine too. It has one hardcoded button (Publish/Stop) and... that's all.

But I need more customizable Flash Player. I need a way to style buttons, to send commands like "start stream" and "stop stream", to catch events like "onconnect"/"ondisconnect" and more. Maybe set quality of video.

Any way there is an Open Source (or not, but it worse) Flash RTMP Webcam Streamer? *Or should I write it by myself?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, I looked into everything Flash Streamers, and answers is: I should write it by myself. There is no available, customazible Open Source Flash Streamers.

Another option is using WebRTC connection between browser and server (!), like Kurento. Then transcode WebRTC => RTMP and only then publish stream to RTMP-server.